# DateTime Format - Getting System.FormatException in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am very new to C#.. I am writing an appointment schedule program where in I want to provide Date and Time value as a string from console and then I want to parse it to `DateTime` format. But by doing so I am getting

> *"System.FormatException" - string was not recognized as a valid datetime*

Here is my piece of code,

```
string Format = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt";
Console.WriteLine("Enter the appointment date and time in(dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM) format");
User_Input = Console.ReadLine();
Date_Time = DateTime.ParseExact(User_Input,Format,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

When I provide input exactly as format i.e like 23/11/2012 08:30 pm.. I am getting the said exception. I want to output datetime with `AM/PM`. What  have I done wrong?

Comment: What is your string looks like? There is no way to help you without this information.

Comment: Please add the User input. Don't make us guess what you entered!

Comment: Overall, people have been using TDD to approach these sorts of programming problems.  Have you considered this approach?

Comment: Sorry guys,, I have provided User_Input as 23/11/2012 08:30 pm

Comment: @SanjayDVG Your format is fine and it works. Take a look at [`Ideone`](http://ideone.com/8o28Bw)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is a little bit odd since your format string works with your given input string(in all cultures) and you want to output with the same format. Perhaps somebody entered `23/11/2012 18:30 pm` instead which does not work with the AM/PM designator.

```
string format = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt";
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("23/11/2012 08:30 pm", format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string output = dateTime.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

outputs: `23/11/2012 08:30 PM`

<kbd>[**demonstration**](http://ideone.com/NRAET3)</kbd>

Note that you can always use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms131044.aspx) to validate user input.

Comment: Hi Tim, but `pm` works also in `ParseExact` which generates `DateTime` with `PM`. I think OP needs to clarify his problem :)